# Web page to install tex

Tags: installing

Using some web page, I tried to install tex on Windows, but with my internet environment it did not succeeed. I want to know other web pages to install.

What web-page do you use to install tex?

Comment: This depends on the distribution you want to install.

Comment: I removed all files related to tex. So, I want to get a full TeX distribution including bibtex.

Comment: But which one ?

Comment: The web-page with which I had tried to install tex is https://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~abenori/soft/abtexinst.html

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstand your question. I do not understand well  about what is "distribution".

Comment: Mainly `MiKTeX` or `TeX Live`.

Comment: Maybe `Tex Live`. (I am not sure what differs between them). Now, I try to install it from https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Comment: Did you download `install-tl-windows.exe`?

Comment: No, I downloaded `install-tl.zip` and executed `install-tl-windows.bat` Now, 1 and a half hours but my PC still continutes installing.

Comment: I've seen on a French documentation it requires  about 2 hours for a full install. But do you need `babel-mongolian`, `hieroglyphic` or  `greek6bc`?

Comment: I am not sure what it is.  Maybe font? Is it required  to select from the three fonts, when I install

Comment: The first is hyphenation patterns when you type in mongolian. Hieroglyphic is afont to reproduce  well… hieroglyphs and greek6bc is an archaic greek font. You also can type in Linear A or Linear B, for Minoan and Mycenian…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Tex and there is LaTex, which is, basically, Tex with predefined libraries. Also there are several distributions (not correct, but think of them like "variants") of LaTex for Windows. Personally, I use MiKTex. From the About page:

> MiKTeX (pronounced mick-tech) is an up-to-date implementation of TeX/LaTeX and related programs.

Homepage: https://miktex.org/

Download page: https://miktex.org/download

You can choose installer, portable and command-line installer. Personally I install it with installer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I did not know what page is official to install tex.

Comment: You are very wellcome. :-)